# Cordova 3.4 FileReader not working (no onloadend)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, filereader

I am updating an app from phonegap 2.* to cordova 3.4
Things are running smooth now, only the file download is not working.

I need to download a file from the internet (host edited) and store it as an JSON file, to have the contents processed later on.
The download is working fine, the file will be shown in the filesystem, but the FileReader does not fire the `onloadend` event.

I have tried a few things like `onprogress` or `onerror` events, also `file.toURI` and `FileReader.readAsDataURL` - nothing worked. Anybody any ideas?

**Notes:**

- `app.log` can be seen as an alias for `console.log`
- `print_r` is defined in another file, working fine
- The downloaded file is just a few kB, shouldn't be a performance issue
- Running on iOS hardware

**Full code (extracted and shortened):**

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

var loadingStatus = 0;
fileTransfer.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {

    // if we have the complete length we can calculate the percentage, otherwise just count up
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        loadingStatus = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
    } else {
        loadingStatus++;
    }
    app.log('Transfer Progress: ' + loadingStatus);

};

fileTransfer.download(
    encodeURI('http://www.example.com/export'),
    'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/import.json',
    function (file) {

        var FileReader = new FileReader();

        FileReader.onloadend = function (evt) {
            app.log('Filereader onloadend');
            app.log(evt);
        };

        FileReader.readAsText(file);

    },
    function (error) {

        // FileTransfer failed
        app.log("FileTransfer Error: " + print_r(error));

    }
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The File API has been updated. See this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/GKoTOSqD2kc

```
file.file(function(e) {
    console.log("called the file func on the file ob");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        app.log('onloadend');
        app.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(e);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant verify this at the moment but since 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins. Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The Command-line Interface, to add or remove this feature for a project:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.file
```

Did you add the plugin to your project?

Comment: Of course all plugins are added and running, otherwise the download would not be possible ;-)

Comment: hmmm, did you check if the onloadstart and onload events fire?

Comment: The events did not fire, seems without the changes from Phillip the `readAsText` function is not called at all. Sadly without any notice by JavaScript or Cordova.